# Why does Mockery return demeter_getMyClass instead of MyClass?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, mockery

I try to mock multiple method calls. As stated [in the documentation](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/demeter_chains.html#mocking-demeter-chains-and-fluent-interfaces), to test the following method calls:

```
$object->foo()->bar()->zebra()->alpha()->selfDestruct();
```

We can use the following piece of code:

```
$mock = \Mockery::mock('CaptainsConsole');
$mock->shouldReceive('foo->bar->zebra->alpha->selfDestruct')->andReturn('Ten!');
```

So, I implemented it:

```
public function testProcessPayment()
{
    $offerPayment =  m::mock('MyApp\Model\Entity\OfferPayment');

    $paymentTransaction = m::mock('MyApp\Model\Entity\PaymentTransaction');
    $paymentTransaction->shouldReceive('getOfferPayment->getOffer')->andReturn($offerPayment);

    $transactionManager = new TransactionManager();
    $transactionManager->processPayment($paymentTransaction);

    $this->assertInstanceOf('Offer', $paymentTransaction->getOfferPayment()->getOffer());
}
```

The related class:

```
class TransactionManager
{
    public function processPayment(PaymentTransaction $paymentTransaction) {
        $itemGroupEntity = $paymentTransaction->getOfferPayment()->getOffer();
    }
}
```

I get:

`Return value of Mockery_3_MyApp_Model_Entity_PaymentTransaction::getOfferPayment() must be an instance of MyApp\Model\Entity\OfferPayment, instance of Mockery_4__demeter_getOfferPayment returned`

---

Implementation of getOfferPayment and getOffer:

```
public function getOfferPayment() : OfferPayment
{
    return $this->offerPayment;
}


public function getOffer() : Offer
{
    return $this->offer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, Mockery does not support [return type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration). 
The issue can be fixed by **removing return type declarations** for the getters:

```
public function getOfferPayment()
{
    return $this->offerPayment;
}


public function getOffer()
{
    return $this->offer;
}
```